# How to create Signup Flow in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am currently working on a multi-page signup page in Flutter. After the user enters his email and password to signup (account is created with firebase), he is asked to upload his profile images on the next signup page.

**The problem:** What if the user leaves the signup page after the account is created on the first signup page and then uses the sign in page to just login. Then the step of uploading images is basically skipped.

**Question:** How can I code the signup process in a way, that even if the user leaves the signup process after the account is created and then logs in, he still has to finish the second signup process (upload profile images) to be able to get redirected to the homepage?

Comment: Record the onboarding data in a local database, define variables to control whenever you start the onboarding and end the process.

Comment: Could you kindly elaborate a little more on that? I don't really know how to implement this

Comment: in your landing page, you are checking whether the user is logged in to redirect him to the home page and to the sign-in page if not right? then you just need to add another check condition that if the `user != null && user.photoUrl is empty || user.photoUrl is null` then redirect to your UploadPhotoScreen().

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That sounds like a good idea. I will try to implement it. Can I get back to you if I have any issues?